# Why VB.NET simple app takes forever to load several lines

Tags: vb.net, performance, while-loop, richtextbox, lines

I have a super simple script that I am using to separate a long list of phone numbers we've gathered from donors over the years into separate area code files.

Obviously, when you have almost 1 million lines it's going to take a while - BUT - if I put in 1,000 it takes less than a second. Once I put in 1 million it takes 10 seconds to do only 5 lines. How could this be?

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    Dim lines As String
    lines = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count
    Dim looper As String = 0
    Dim path As String = "c:\acs\"
    MsgBox("I have " + lines + " lines to do.")
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
    End If
    Dim i As String = 0

    For loops As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
        Dim ac As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(looper).ToString
        ac = ac.Substring(0, 3)
        Dim strFile As String = path + ac + ".txt"
        Dim sw As StreamWriter
        sw = File.AppendText(strFile)
        sw.WriteLine(RichTextBox1.Lines(looper))
        sw.Close()
        Label1.Text = String.Format("Processing item {0} of {1}", looper, lines)
        looper = looper + 1
    Next
    MsgBox("done now")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: IT may be its loading the whole file into memory.  Try reading line by line or splitting into smaller files.

Comment: as others have hinted below, my advice would to be not use the rtb for this, not quite sure what it is as a web dev, but there's a very standard way to handle to file reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx . I've never had performance issues with the SR object, but... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx offers a way to add a buffer, though I'm pretty sure there's some safeguards on the SR object in place already.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you use the RichTextBox.Lines properties, VB.Net will need to split the content by CR+LF pair. Thus your `For loops As Integer = - To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count-1` is really a performance hit.
Try to use:

```
For Each vsLine As String in RichTextBox1.Lines
```

instead. It will be a lot faster. Alternatively, if you must use For loop, then get it once:

```
Dim vasLines() As String = RichTextBox1.Lines
For viLines As Integer = 0 to UBound(vasLines.Count)
    '....
Next
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're performing UI updates in your For loop.  That will take time.

You're updating the UI in a thread that is not the main thread which might impact performance.  You should not use the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls method.  You should update the UI properly using the ReportProgress method of the BackgroundWorker.

You are opening and closing a file for each iteration of the loop.  That will take time as well.

I think a better method would be to add the data to a Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)), with the area code as the key and the list would hold all the number for that area code.  Once the Dictionary is filled, loop through the keys and write the numbers out.